# next.js cannot find my video and gif files despite having intellisense

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, video, next.js13

[image: The code]

I am trying to add a video to my Next.js file, but it seems that Next.js cannot find it. The video file is named video.mp4 and it is not showing up in the browser. I have tried converting the video to GIF, but that did not work either. I also tried moving the video file to the public folder, but that still did not work. The video works fine in .jsx files, but it does not work in .tsx files. I am not sure what is causing the problem